# iPhone XS Max | Swift 4.2 | App crashing libsystem_kernel.dylib abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal + 104

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, swift4.2, xcode10.1

After updating to iOS 12.1.2, and updating new version from App Store. App keeps crashing on launch.

Got the report from crashlitics but not helpful. Anyone can suggest what to do?

Date: 2019-01-03T06:48:00Z

OS Version: 12.1.2

Device: iPhone XS Max

RAM Free: 3.8%

Disk Free: 81.6%

## 1. Crashed: com.apple.root.default-qos

> 0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x22193fdd4 __abort_with_payload + 8
> 1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x221939594
> abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal + 104 2  (Missing)
> 0x28ec82219395c8 (Missing) 3  (Missing)
> 0x4a728224c6f9fc (Missing) 4  (Missing)
> 0x6d688224c6f92c (Missing) 5  (Missing)
> 0x66cd0224c73cbc (Missing) 6  (Missing)
> 0x3e2e8221a01324 (Missing) 7  (Missing)
> 0x748c02219f4430 (Missing) 8  (Missing)
> 0x130d02217b9378 (Missing) 9  (Missing)
> 0x1b1382217d0f28 (Missing) 10 (Missing)
> 0x552902217c8e74 (Missing) 11 (Missing)
> 0x613182219b9b30 (Missing) 12 (Missing)
> 0x39f882219bfdd4 (Missing)

## 0. com.apple.main-thread

> 0  "libobjc.A.dylib"                0x220facf4c
> _NXMapMember(_NXMapTable*, void const*, void**) + 232

Comment: Can you provide symbolicated stack trace? It seems like you haven't uploaded .dsym file to Crashlitics

Comment: Even after uploading .dsym, nothing happens

Comment: Well that's a blocker issue now in order to resolve this one. You might contact Crashlitics support or ask another question on SO regarding this. I wish I could help but I'm not using Crashlitics.

Comment: @shashank mishra Did you find solution for it? I am also facing same issue....!

Comment: @ShashankMishra Are u able to solve this issue ? I also got the same report from crashlytics.

Comment: Have you uploaded correct dSYM files to crashlytics. It looks you cannot symbolicate crash log. Another possible solution is to check if Xcode has symbolicated crash logged in Organizer.

Comment: @Vidhyanand did you find any solutions ?

Comment: @nivritgupta . Posted my solution once check it. It may helps you.

Answer (score -3):

Since the iPhone X and later models, the faceID is applied without applying the touchID